# How do I prevent lag when using mouse.Listener() with pynput?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

When using the `mouse.Listener()` function in pynput, my cursor lags and becomes almost unusable. Is there any way to prevent this lag, or is it simply a consequence of using pynput?

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pynput import mouse

side_button_held = False

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global side_button_held
    if button == mouse.Button.x2 and pressed:
        side_button_held = True
        print("Side button is held down")
    elif button == mouse.Button.x2:
        side_button_held = False
        print("Side button is released")
        
listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()

while True:
    if side_button_held:
        screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None)
        img = np.array(screenshot)
        rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        cv2.imshow("Screen", rgb_img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I tried adding a delay each time the loop runs by using the `time.sleep()` function in order to reduce the load on my computer, but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using win32api instead of pynput.